# C#: Flip image horizontally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, image, rotation

What I'm trying to do is, to flip image horizontally on radio button click.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    arrow.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    arrow.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
}
```

The code above doesn't flip image: image stays as it is. What am I missing?

Comment: @user1428799 arrow is image conatiner's name

Comment: Are you sure that this code is called?

Comment: WriteableBitmapExtensions has rotate/flip methods: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: @user1428799 can you take a look with teamviewer? I'm actually newbie to C#

Comment: Is arrow a PictureBox control?

Comment: And you may need to force it to redraw, so try adding a `arrow.Invalidate();` after it

Comment: @user1428799 invalidate worked. But only 1 time. I added after both flips

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13387/c-flip-image-horizontally

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cause it to redraw, you can force this manually by doing

```
 private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     arrow.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
     arrow.Invalidate() ;
 }
```

You should also only have this on  one of the radio buttons, not both, otherwise they'll negate each other, so replace your current stuff with the above. Just verified it works under vs2005, don't have vs2010 handy