# Rotate and flip an image

Tags: c#, .net

I want to flip an image horizontally. This would occur when the user clicks a button. I am creating the `Image` in C# like this:

```
Image newImage = new Image();
```

I tried:

```
ScaleTransform transform = new ScaleTransform();
transform.ScaleY = -1;
SelectedImage.RenderTransform = transform;    //Where SelectedImage is the Image I want to rotate.
```

to flip it, but nothing I do will flip it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this WPF? If so, then this is not valid code (`ScaleY` is a property, not a method).

Comment: No, it's a UWP app. But you're right. I was writing this from memory. Will fix.

Comment: OK, I don't have any experience in UWP unfortunately. If this was WPF, you would need to do `transform.ScaleX = -1` (`ScaleY` will flip vertically) and also `transform.CenterX = newImage.Width/2` (so that it stays in the same location).

Comment: Will try that when I get VS fired up, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, which is based on something I use in a Universal Windows Platform app I'm currently working on, which works for me:

```
newImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point { X = 0.5, Y = 0.5 };
newImage.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleY = -1 };
newImage.UpdateLayout();
```

I think UpdateLayout is the key part here to get this to work as I think I had same issue with it not updating and this might have resolved it

Answer (score 1):

Lacking any experience whatsoever with the DotNet Image class, have you tried the System.Drawing.Image.RotateFlip function?  Please see the below links.

It looks like this may do what you want.

```
Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
```

You may have problems with the image not redrawing after you flip it.  You may need to call Invalidate() to indicate that the image/area should be redrawn.

[C#: Flip image horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318134/c-flip-image-horizontally)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this being done with .NET, but..

I recommend this good library. I am pretty sure you can flip images and rotate images with it
http://magick.codeplex.com/

It has a Flip() method in there.
Also a Rotate() method. The methods work just the same.

```
MagickImage example = new MagickImage("myimage.PNG");
example.Rotate(90); // Rotates 90 degrees counter clockwise
example.Write();
```

Hope I helped :)